# dom-repeat filter/sort redraw error

Tags: polymer, web-component

I have an issue with the way `dom-repeat` redraws. The snippet below demonstrates that filtering and sorting a simple array of objects can present data incorrectly to the end user.

I have determined this to be related to the reuse of instances within the `_applyFullRefresh` method (https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/lib/template/dom-repeat.html#L482).

I was able to modify this method to create a working solution by reusing instances with the matching key.  A diff of this can be seen here: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/compare/master...TomK:patch-1

**My Question:** Is a patch to `dom-repeat` this the only way I can achieve a working example?

**Snippet Expected Result:**
With any combination of filter/sort selected, the two numbers on a single line (`item content` and `x-item content`) should always be the same.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="description" content="basic polymer jsbin">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="//polygit.org/components/">
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">

    
  <dom-module id="x-item-test">
    <template>
      x-item content: [[_innerText]]
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(
        function ()
        {
          Polymer(
            {
              is:           'x-item-test',
              properties:   {
                _innerText: {type: String}
              },
              attached:     function ()
                            {
                              Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, this.__updateProp.bind(this));
                              new MutationObserver(this.__updateProp.bind(this))
                                .observe(this, {childList: true, subtree: true, characterData: true});
                            },
              __updateProp: function ()
                            {
                              var nodes = this.getEffectiveChildNodes(), output = '';
                              for(var i in nodes)
                              {
                                var n = nodes[i];
                                if(n.nodeType == 3 && n.nodeValue)
                                {
                                  output += n.nodeValue;
                                }
                              }
                              this._innerText = output;
                            }
            }
          );
        }
      );
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="test-app">
    <template>
      <div>
        Filter <input type="checkbox" checked="{{_applyFilter::change}}">
      </div>
      <div>
        Sort <input type="checkbox" checked="{{_reverse::change}}">
      </div>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[actions]]" filter="{{_filter(_applyFilter)}}" sort="{{_sort(_reverse)}}">
        <div>Item content: [[item.id]] -
          <x-item-test>[[item.id]]
            <div>ignored</div>
          </x-item-test>
        </div>
      </template>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(
        function ()
        {
          Polymer(
            {
              is:         'test-app',
              properties: {
                actions:      {
                  type:  Array,
                  value: [{id: '1', primary: true}, {id: '2'}, {id: '3', primary: true}, {id: '4'}]
                },
                _applyFilter: {type: Boolean, value: false},
                _reverse:     {type: Boolean, value: false}
              },
              _filter:    function (applyFilter)
                          {
                            return function (item)
                            {
                              return !applyFilter || item.primary;
                            }
                          },
              _sort:      function (reverse)
                          {
                            return function (a, b)
                            {
                              if(reverse)
                              {
                                return a.id < b.id
                              }
                              return a.id >= b.id;
                            }
                          }
            }
          );
        }
      );
    </script>
  </dom-module>

</head>
<body>
<test-app></test-app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is the data presented incorrectly?

Comment: Please run the snippet, the `item content` and `x-item content` should match when clicking any combination of check boxes

Comment: I did run it, but it's not clear in your question what the expected outcome is.

Comment: Ah i see, thank you. i'll update the question with the expected result

Comment: Hmm. I tried your snippet with 2.0-preview and still see the same behavior.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I'll remove the note until I can test further. Thank you

Comment: I re-tested with 2.0-preview and Chrome 54/56, which resolves the issue. So it seems the workaround is to upgrade Polymer to 2.0-preview and Chrome 54+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Polymer 1.x, because of the way `dom-repeat` reuses instances, I don't think there's a good way to do what you're trying to do.

Doing a property binding instead of passing light DOM children to `x-item-test` would be the best way to do this in 1.x.

Doing the instance lookup for each array item is O(n^2) I think so wouldn't be acceptable for the general case.

If you really need to use light DOM children for some reason, the last (rather horrible) option I can think of is to have a dom-change listener that walks the template instances and calls some update method on them.

I can't imagine any use case where this would be preferrable to property binding, but sometimes I'm not very imaginative.

I'm not seeing this issue with 2.0-preview:

http://jsbin.com/vuritog/2/edit?html,output

Hope that helps.

Comment: Interesting. I confirmed the issue doesn't occur in 2.0-preview with Chrome 56, but still occurs in Chrome 53 (which is what I was testing with earlier).

Comment: Thanks @DocDude, based on your feedback we're rethinking our approach.  I've created an issue in core regarding text node distribution.